# Do inductors with larger radius have "deeper" magnetic fields?

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

In the case of an inductor shaped as a coil....

How can you calculate how a magnetic field changes with distance from the inductor? How can you vary the inductor parameters to have a magnetic field that extends far away from the end of an inductor?

An inductor with a small radius has a high inductance. Does its magnetic field magnitude fall off quicker by distance due to its small radius? Is the magnetic field magnitude bigger at a distance due to its high initial magnitude?

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in one post. As for the question of how to have a magnetic field that is still strong far from the inductor, any coil inductor is going to look like a point magnetic dipole at large distances from it, and all magnetic dipoles show the same characteristic drop-off in magnetic field strength with distance. So any coil inductor which gives a relatively strong magnetic field at short distances will also give a relatively strong magnetic field at large distances.

Comment: Thanks. Are you aware of any scripts, applications or web apps for determining the magnetic field magnitude a point distant from an inductor, where you can modulate inductor parameters to figure out the magnetic field? Or just an equation? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Equation: 
$dB = \frac{\mu*I*dL}{4*\pi}*\frac{R}{(z^2 + R^2)^\frac{3}{2}} $

Look at HyperPhysics tutorial http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/curloo.html#c1. They show how to calculate a magnetic field at a point based on a loop of wire (Equation Above) and will explain that so I don't need to repeat it.

You can then edit this equation to solve for a coil (as the left part of the equation is the magnetic field of the loop). I would start there.

As for scripts I know there are ones built into software: Like MatLab and such. Hyperphysics also has some calculators online for free.